# openpyxl TypeError: SheetFormatProperties.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'defaultColWidthPt'

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
def manytoonebyspire():
    import openpyxl
    from spire.xls import Workbook
    from spire.xls import ExcelVersion
    workbook=Workbook()
    workbook.LoadFromFile('manysheetbook.xlsx')
    workbook1=Workbook()
    workbook1.CreateEmptySheets(1)
    i=0
    for sheet in workbook.Worksheets:
        if i==0:
            newsheet = workbook1.Worksheets[i]
            newsheet.Name = sheet.Name
            newsheet.CopyFrom(sheet)
            i=i+1
        else:
            workbook1.CreateEmptySheet()
            newsheet = workbook1.Worksheets[i]
            newsheet.Name = sheet.Name
            newsheet.CopyFrom(sheet)
            i=i+1


    workbook1.SaveToFile('123.xlsx',ExcelVersion.Version2010)
    workbook.Dispose()


    wk = openpyxl.load_workbook('123.xlsx')
    print(wk.sheetnames[-1])
    del wk[wk.sheetnames[-1]]
    wk.save('123-1.xlsx')



if __name__=='__main__':
    import time
    starttime=time.time()
    manytoonebyspire()
    endtime=time.time()
    print(endtime-starttime)
```

```
when wk = openpyxl.load_workbook('123.xlsx')
Prompt error"TypeError: SheetFormatProperties.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'defaultColWidthPt'"
```

How can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Suggests an [issue with your Excel file](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1791). Check another Excel file (preferably not from the same source) with your code and also check how the Excel files was created.